# What cookie does a .NET ADFS claims aware web application return to the client browser on receipt of a valid token?

Tags: .net, iis-7, saml, adfs

When a client browser first provides a valid SAML token to the web application (by POST), the application processes the token and returns an authentication cookie.

Is this cookie the standard ASPXAUTH cookie that would be returned from forms authentication, or does it represent/contain the SAML token?

If it's the latter, then is there a configuration in the standard ADFS setup for .NET web applications on the IIS to allow switching to ASPXAUTH once the initial token is validated?

Would there be disadvantages to doing this?

Comment: Would there be Advantages to doing this? I can't think of any off-hand - why do you want this option?

Comment: Mainly because a SAML token can get quite large and we want to support mobile devices. Round tripping the whole token might be a bit extravagant for mobile data usage / delivery speed, especially on low quality networks. I think your answer below provides a route for us, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of the login process, once the token has been received and accepted, the [`WSFederationAuthenticationModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.wsfederationauthenticationmodule.aspx) calls the [`SessionAuthenticationModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.sessionauthenticationmodule.aspx)s [`WriteSessionTokenToCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.sessionauthenticationmodule.writesessiontokentocookie.aspx) method:

```
public void WriteSessionTokenToCookie(SessionSecurityToken sessionToken)
{
    //Error checking omitted
    byte[] buffer = handler.WriteToken(sessionToken);
    SessionSecurityTokenCacheKey key = new SessionSecurityTokenCacheKey(this.CookieHandler.Path, sessionToken.ContextId, sessionToken.KeyGeneration);
    DateTime expiryTime = DateTimeUtil.Add(sessionToken.ValidTo, base.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.MaxClockSkew);
    handler.Configuration.Caches.SessionSecurityTokenCache.AddOrUpdate(key, sessionToken, expiryTime);
    this.CookieHandler.Write(buffer, sessionToken.IsPersistent, sessionToken.ValidTo);
}
```

Which as you can see is writing *some* form of the token, suitably serialized, as cookie(s). Exactly what is included in this depends on some options - for instance, [`SaveBootstrapContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.configuration.identityconfigurationelement.savebootstrapcontext.aspx) may affect exactly what is stored. If this option is turned on then, yes, I believe the SAML token is stored in the cookie.

So, what cookie is stored? That depends on what `this.CookieHandler` is doing. By default, this is the [`ChunkedCookieHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.chunkedcookiehandler.aspx) which ultimately (again, by default) will split the binary blob that the above method call passes it into multiple smaller blobs, and store those in a series of cookies of the form `FedAuth1`, `FedAuth2`, etc.

> is there a configuration in the standard ADFS setup for .NET web applications on the IIS to allow switching to ASPXAUTH once the initial token is validated

Not so far as I'm aware.

Comment: So if I'm developing a native iOS mobile app I'll have to implement cookie handling for a set of n cookies, rather than a single named cookie?

Comment: @JamesWalford - yes, you'll need to accommodate multiple cookies. I would hope that iOS would have some sort of component (like .NET's [`CookieContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.aspx)) that would handle the job for you, but iOS is a long way away from my usual stamping grounds, so I've not got any recommendations.